# How to include a new message extended from DemoSafetyMessage in the MyVeinsApp application?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I created a new safety messsage that is extended from the DemoSafetyMessage:

```
import veins.modules.messages.DemoSafetyMessage;
namespace veins;
packet NewSafetyMsg extends DemoSafetyMessage {
double senderAngle;
double PowRxdBmAvg;
}
```

I include this new message into the MyVeinsApp application and pass it to the onBSM function in both the .cc and .h files of MyVeinsApp.

```
#include "veins/modules/messages/NewSafetyMsg_m.h"

void onBSM(NewSafetyMsg* bsm) override; // in the .h file

#include "veins/modules/messages/NewSafetyMsg_m.h" //in the .cc file
```

However, I am getting this error in the .h file.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type ‘void veins::MyVeinsApp::onBSM(veins::NewSafetyMsg*)’ marked ‘override’, but does not override MyVeinsApp.h    /veins/src/veins/modules/application/traci  line 50 C/C++ Problem
```

I know that MyVeinsApp is extending the DemoBaseApplLayer which takes DemoSafetyMessage, So there should be no problem!! What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From TraciDemo11p example:

1. In .h file you need to keep the same method as that of parent class

   void onBSM(DemoSafetyMessage* bsm) override;
2. In .cc file The extended message (i.e. NewSafetyMessage) should be dynamically casted to parent message type (i.e. DemoSafetyMessage)

   void MyVeinsApp::onBSM(DemoSafetyMessage* bsm)

   {

   NewSafetyMessage* bsm1 = check_and_cast<NewSafetyMessage*>(bsm);

   ......

   ......

Comment: Thank you, for the answer. I discovered this yesterday. However, what is the different between dynamic_cast and check_and_cast ??

Comment: From OMNET++ documentation:. check_and_cast() is used to Cast an object pointer to the given C++ type and throw exception if fails.           The method calls dynamic_cast<T>(p) where T is a type you supplied; if the result is NULL (which indicates incompatible types), an exception is thrown. You may refer the omnet++ doc for more info.

Answer (score 1):

void onBSM(DemoSafetyMessage* bsm) override; //parent class

void onBSM(NewSafetyMsg* bsm) override; //child class

Function overriding in C++ does'nt work with parameter mismatch.

Comment: Yes, I know that from the inheritance. So, what is the correct way to use a new message in an OMNET++/veins project extended from the Demo application?